# Android Layouts -"wrap_content" is not allowing elements to the right to be displayed if the content width is too wide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-wrap-content

This piece I am working on has a design requirement to show on one row some text, followed by an image. The image should always be aligned next to the text like this:

[Some Text] [Img]

[Some longer Text] [Img]

For this, I'm using the "wrap_content" modifier on the width of the text. The issue, however, is when the text is long enough to take up the width of the screen the image is not shown. I am looking for something to help me limit the length of the width (cannot be done dynamically as this needs to load quickly) so that this will always reserve enough space for the image at the end of the line.

So far the only way I've been able to accomplish this is by using a fix width TextView which ends up justifying the image to the same spot on every line, which is not desired. Using anything other than "wrap_content" either requires me to dynamically set the width at run-time or incorrectly creates the TextView wider or narrower than it should be, and the "wrap_content" seems to be what is making it so the image does not display. I have tried RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout, and LinearLayout to achieve this and all seem to have the same issue.

Comment: It's impossible to show img if the text is too long because the row length is limited.

Comment: Thanks for your response but can you explain what you mean? The row length is of course limited by the parent element's width but even when i try to confine the element to the max width of a guideline it will still overflow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:drawableRight` to display your image instead of using a separate `ImageView`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/android"
    android:text="short text"/>
```

[image]

[image]

You can use `android:gravity` to control the vertical position of the text/image and `android:drawablePadding` to control the space between the image and the text.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you for the detail and examples